# OnClickListener of ImageView is not Working

Tags: android, android-activity, nullpointerexception, imageview, onclicklistener

image123(ImageView) works normal but when it comes to ONclickListener it does not work even after using different methods of Calling the listener.

I put func(),which contain findviewbyid of image123 (ImageView) just after SetContentView() and it works fine .OnclickListener of image123 does not works when func() is in OnClicklistener of Reset Button as Shown in the Code.

### Problem:

How can i call the func() in reset button onclicklistener as well as in start at Oncreate() Activity?

It catch an exception shown in Log cat

> **- Exception at Onclick Listener" ,"java.lang.NullPointerException**

```
     public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     ImageView image123;
  
    int[] resultid=new int[25];

        Button buttonExit;
      Button buttonreset;



            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
     buttonreset=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_reset);
     buttonExit=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_exit);
     
     v1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
     v2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.fruit_count);
     //--------------------------Exit Button---------------------------
     buttonExit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        
            finish();
            
        }
    });
    
    //*******************Exception comes here*********************       
     try{
     image123.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
    
            Log.d("Listner Called", "Listner Called");
        
        }
    });
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
         
         Log.d("Exception at onclickListener", e.toString());
         
     }


     buttonreset.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                
 func();
        
        }});
}


void func()
{
    String as=null; 
    int resultid;
    
    
    SecureRandom random=new SecureRandom();
image123=new ImageView(this);
    as=("img"+1).toString();
    resultid=getResources().getIdentifier(as, "id","com.example.selectiongame"      );
    Log.d(as, ""+resultid);
    image123=(ImageView) findViewById(resultid);



    as="drawable"+(random.nextInt(3)+1);
    resultid = getResources().getIdentifier(as, "drawable", "com.example.selectiongame");
    Log.d(as, ""+resultid);
    image123.setImageResource(resultid);
}
```

Comment: What does "it does not work" mean? What happens when you compile and run your app?

Comment: OnclickListener Function does not run ... No effect on Click

Comment: Please provide a *complete*, short example that illustrates your problem. At the moment, you provide two try...catch blocks without any context to show where these are in your code. I suggest that you create a new small project with a single `ImageView` and set its `OnClickListener`. If you can get that to work, go a step further by creating an array with only **two** `ImageView`s. As you get things working, add a little bit more at a time. If at any time, you encounter problems, you will be able to show a small amount of code here with your question.

Comment: Code-Gur0 , i have simplized the code and OnclickListener Exception is Still Coming But this is simplicized one .you can see it

Comment: What exception do you get? Please post the *exact* error message.

Comment: As a side note, Google strongly discourages Exit buttons or menu items. These are just not necessary on the Android platform.

Comment: Its a nullpointerexception caught at OnsetOnclickListner
,it is a old unsolved assignment so Exit button was a Part of Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You must not findviewbyid() of an ImageView in some other function other than Oncreate(Bundle b) or Some Listener(e.g OnclickListener ,onselectionchange etc) . if you want to findviewbyid(...) of a view in a function other than Oncreate ,Atleast Call that function once after SetContentView() and other prerequisite Findviewbyid(...).

2.
In order to Refresh your Activity ,when you can not use function containing findviewbyid(...) of ImageView,like in my case,  in body some button(e.g Refresh ,Reset) OnclickListner .You must write the following code

```
     buttonreset.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

 Bundle newBundle=new Bundle();
 onCreate(newBundle);

//func();     >>We can not use this func() here if we are using it in Oncreate(...) in case of Array of ImageView

        }});
}
```

For views other than Imageview ,Maybe Regular Line of Code work ...But in case of ImageView or Array of ImageView ....These things must be kept in mind and Simply Oncreate() must be used to Refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an array of ResIDs and an array of ImageViews.  Then do something like this instead of initializing them with findViewById()...

```
for(int i = 0; i < res_arr.length; i++)
{
    images[i] = new ImageView(this);
    images[i].setImageResource(res_arr[i]);
    images[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("Button_Clicked", "Button Clicked");
        }
    });
}
```